# Getting form element by value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hey guys I have a form which is stated below

```
<td><input type="text" id="NumberofRisks" name="Yeses" style="width: 25px" value ="<?php echo $row['Total-Score'];?> " </td>
```

The form has some data from a table as a value and I would like to take this value into my Javascript from to do a simple calculation. The function is listed below.

```
function sum()
{
    sumField = document.getElementById("NumberofRisks");
    var sum = 0;

    $("input[name^='yanswer']:checked").each(function(){
    sum++;        

    });

        sumField.value = sum;
}
```

I need to get that value into the function as the value where it says NumberofRisks. Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: I changed it, it was trying to put the table row in there but to no avail.

Comment: as a sidenote... is there a reason you mixing JS and jquery selector?

Comment: What user action triggers this calculation? That might help determine the answer.

Comment: @Teemu look at the HTML code, its an input field

Comment: Do you mean that you want the `sum` variable to start with the initial value of `#NumberofRisks`, instead of starting at 0?

Comment: This is the user action <input type="button" value="Click for Total Number of Risks" name="Riskfactors" onclick="sum()" ></input></td>

Comment: @ggzone I want to make the sum which is equal to 0 currently equal to the Total-Score which is stored in the database which I can access with PHP normally.

Comment: @ZougenMoriver Yes! :) I want it to start at the number that comes from <?php  $row['Total-Score'];?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to set `sum` to the initial value of `#NumberofRisks`.

```
var prevCheckedCount = 0;

function sum()
{
    var sumField = document.getElementById("NumberofRisks");

    // start sum with the inital value in HTML from DB
    var valueOnClick = Math.floor(sumField.value);
    var thisCheckedCount = 0;

    $("input[name^='yanswer']:checked").each(function(){
         thisCheckedCount++;
    });

    if(thisCheckedCount <= prevCheckedCount) {
        sumField.value = valueOnClick - prevCheckedCount + thisCheckedCount;
    } else {
        sumField.value =valueOnClick + thisCheckedCount;
    }

    prevCheckedCount = thisCheckedCount;
}
```

Here's this code working: http://jsfiddle.net/t5hG4/

Answer (score 1):

In order to grab the value of the input box you can use the following javascript:

```
var sum = document.getElementById("NumberofRisks").value;
```

Is this what you're trying to achieve?

As a side note, in the example you provided you did not close the `input box` so that might be giving you some errors as well.

EDIT:

If you're looking for a pure Javascript way to do this see below:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var sum = document.getElementById("NumberofRisks").value;

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    if (elements[i].checked) {
        sum++
    }
}
```

See fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/es26j/

Comment: I don't think this answer alone will work for you - if you tick some boxes, click update, and then untick some boxes and click update again, your NumberofRisks value will not decrease to reflect the changes.

Comment: Yes this has worked for me. I need to figure that out now too @ZougenMoriver.

Comment: See my answer for that.